# Marshmallow field lookup on deserialisation

Tags: python, marshmallow

Is it possible to perform input data lookups with `marshmallow` schemas ? The following does not work.. :

```py
class ParentSchema(Schema):
    child_name = fields.String(data_key="child.fname")
```

Then during deserialisation:

```py
data = {"child": {"fname": "John", "lname": "Doe"}}
ParentSchema().load(data)
```

The result is `{}`.

<sup>marshmallow-v3.14.1</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `fields.Function`:

```py
class ParentSchema(Schema):
    child_name = fields.Function(data_key="child",
                                 deserialize=lambda child: child["fname"])

data = {"child": {"fname": "John", "lname": "Doe"}}
ParentSchema().load(data)
```

And the result is `{'child_name': 'John'}`.

Comment: I tried that one before but eventually missed the ```data_key``` .. thanks !